# Java Exception printing twice

Tags: java, exception, console, printing

I know the exception is kind of pointless, but I was trying to learn how to use / create exceptions so I used this. The only problem is for some reason my error message generated by my exception is printing to console twice.

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Project3
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      String inputFileName = null;
      if (args.length > 0)
        inputFileName = args[0];
      File inputFile = FileGetter.getFile(
          "Please enter the full path of the input file: ", inputFileName);

      String outputFileName = null;
      if (args.length > 1)
        outputFileName = args[1];
      File outputFile = FileGetter.getFile(
          "Please enter the full path of the output file: ", outputFileName);

      Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
      PrintStream out = new PrintStream(outputFile);
      Person person = null;

      // Read records from input file, get an object from the factory,
      // output the class to the output file.
      while(in.hasNext())
      {
        String personRecord = in.nextLine();

        person = PersonFactory.getPerson(personRecord);

        person.display(); 

        person.output(out);
      }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}





import java.util.Scanner;

class Student extends Person
{
  private double gpa;

  public Student()
  {
    super();
    gpa = 0.0;
  }

  public Student(String firstName, String lastName, double gpa)
  {
    super(firstName, lastName);
    this.gpa = gpa;
  }

  public String toString(){
   try{
        if (gpa >= 0.0 && gpa <= 4.0){
            return super.toString() + "\n\tGPA: " + gpa;
        }
        else {
            throw new InvalidGpaException();
        }
    }
   catch (InvalidGpaException e){
       System.out.println(e);
       return super.toString() + "\n\tGPA: " + gpa;
   }
  }

  public void display()
  {
    System.out.println("<<Student>>" + this);
  }

  @Override
  public void input(Scanner in)
  {
    super.input(in);

    if (in.hasNextDouble())
    {
      this.gpa = in.nextDouble();
    }
  }

  class InvalidGpaException extends Exception {
    public InvalidGpaException() {
        super("Invalid GPA: " + gpa);
      }
  }
}
```

This is my console readout. Not sure what's causing the exception to print twice.

```
project3.Student$InvalidGpaException: Invalid GPA: -4.0
<< Student>>
        Id: 2        Doe, Junior
        GPA: -4.0
project3.Student$InvalidGpaException: Invalid GPA: -4.0
```

edit: The main code is on the top. The input is a file designated by the user. What I shown right here is my console printout, not what is returned to the output file. The output file shows the exact same thing minus the error message. The Error message from the exception (which I know is not necessary) is only printed to the console. I don't see where I'm printing it twice.

Comment: Seeing the code that's running this (probably your `main` method) would be most helpful.

Comment: The main code is up now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that your `Person.output()` method has a call to `toString()` in it, which will print the exception before returning the proper string, which doesn't show up because you're outputting it to `out`.

E: If you want my deduction, here it is:  The first error message and normal message are printed out within the call to `display()`, as it should be.  Immediately after that is the `output()` call, which by the name I guess is meant to do what `display()` does, except to a file.  However, you forgot that the exception is printed directly to `System.out`, so it appears in the console, while the string that `toString()` actually returns is written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

What is your main ? what is your INPUT..
Change your exception to something different.

Where are you printing this data ?

```
<< Student>>
        Id: 2        Doe, Junior
        GPA: -4.0
```

Are you sure you aren't calling person.toString() twice ?

Comment: That data is printed to both console and an output file, the console alone receives the error data.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are calling `toString` somewhere in the code you have not shown to us.

Putting in a `Thread.dumpStack();` in the `toString` implementation should tell you from where.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
System.out.println(e);
   return super.toString() + "\n\tGPA: " + gpa;
```

to

```
System.out.println(e);
```

(Or something similar)

Comment: I get an error if I do that, there has to be return in there.