# System.out call printing twice

Tags: java, printing, console, boolean

I put off asking this as it must be something daft and, given it was also me who asked this, I hesitated and have spent the last few hours getting increasingly frustrated:
[Last line of for loop executed twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639122/last-line-of-for-loop-executed-twice)

I think it might be a similar sort of oversight.

I also found this, which deals with a similar problem:
[Java Exception printing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186148/java-exception-printing-twice)

but still can't seem to fix mine.

Here is a snippet from one class:

```
switch (Integer.parseInt(oc, 16)) 
{
  case 0x0F:
  ccrFlagState.zBit(true);
  break;
}
```

Which calls this snippet in another:

```
public boolean zBit(boolean set) {

    if (set = true) {
        System.out.println("Z set in CCR class");
    }
    return set;
}
```

When I input `0F` the console prints `Z set in CCR class` twice.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why? Thanks, Robert.

-EDIT-
I should add that I get the same result with:

```
if (set)
```

and

```
if (set == true)
```

Comment: @thinksteep It does return `true`, in fact, it always does. When you assign a value to a variable the output is the value you assigned. The problem is, I think, it shouldn't be an assignment?

Comment: double `=` for comparison: `if (set == true)` or simply `if (set)`. Don't know why this is causing 2 prints from the code shown

Comment: I'm on Java6 and yes, it seems to compile and run fine.

Comment: @TheZ: you are correct, I have removed my comment

Comment: Thanks folks - I've tried "if (set == true)" and "if(set)"
All give the same result.

Comment: Is it not possible that the previous `case` in your `switch` statement falls through?

Comment: The problem is not covered by the provided code snippets. Please provide more code that really makes this problem reproducable for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not reproducable for me. This code only pints it out once. Please provide more code ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String oc = "0F";

    switch (Integer.parseInt(oc, 16)) {
      case 0x0F:
          zBit(true);
          break;
    }
}


public static boolean zBit(boolean set) {
    if (set) {
        System.out.println("Z set in CCR class");
    }
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Have to write this as an answer, because it' too much for a comment.

Comment: Hi Fabian,

There is another piece of code in the GUI class and it does indeed jump past it, printing "Z is set".:
`if (ccrFlags.zBit(false)) {
   Z.setText(unset);
  } else {
   Z.setText(flagSet);
   System.out.println("Z is set");
  }`

I guess there's something wrong with the first part of the "if" statement?

Answer (score 3):

(Your condition needs to be `set == true`. `set = true` assigns the variable to `true` and then always evaluates to `true`.)

How sure are you that you are not calling `zBit` twice? Use a debugger to know for sure.

You don't have some kind of logging wrapper or system possibly intercepting and repeating `System.out` lines?

Comment: Or even more succintly: `if ( set )`. It's much more readable.

Comment: Completely agree, was just trying to highlight the nature of the error. `== true` is always redundant.

Comment: @Sean:
I think it is calling zBit twice right enough. Not sure why yet but I'm trying to figure it out with the debugger.

Many thanks for your help.